# IEEEbiography not complying properly

Tags: ieeetran, algorithm2e, biography

I am trying to compile the following code that contains a biography at the end such that

```
\newif\iffinal
\finaltrue 
%\finalfalse
\iffinal
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran} %
\else
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn,draftcls]{IEEEtran} %
\fi

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\else
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\fi

\SetKw{return}{return}
\SetKw{throw}{throw}
\SetKw{event}{event}
\SetKw{break}{break}

\begin{document}

......

\begin{IEEEbiography}{Name} 
received his B.S degree from.......
\end{IEEEbiography}

\end{document}
```

I keep getting an error

```
use of \\ieeebiography doesnt match its definition. 
Argument of \@break has an extra }
Runaway argument?
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

After trying so many times, I realized that what's causing this issue is the     `\SetKw{break}{break}` which I use as a keyword in my algorithms.

How can I define the word `break` without causing this issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The example doesn't stop for me.

Comment: The culprit is `\SetKw{break}{break}`, which defines `\break` to give 'break' in pseudocode listings. But `IEEEbiography` needs `\break` with a different meaning. Hence the clash. If you can live without `\break` in your pseudocode just drop `\SetKw{break}{break}`, if you absolutely need 'break' rename the macro `\SetKw{algbreak}{break}` lets you use `\algbreak`.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example that reproduces the issue is

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\SetKw{break}{break}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\While{condition}{%
  \break
}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}}]{Prof.\ van Duck}
Prof.\ van Duck is an esteemed scientist at the University of Quackland.
\end{IEEEbiography}
\end{document}
```

The issue is that `\SetKw{break}{break}` redefines `\break` which is defined in `latex.ltx` as `\def\break{\penalty-\@M}` without further warning. The documentation of [`algorithm2e` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) mentions this briefly in §11.

The `IEEEbiography` environment uses `\break`, but since it has been redefined to mean something completely different that command now causes an error.

A simple solution would be to pick a different command name for your break instruction in `algorithm2e`

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\SetKw{algobreak}{break}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\While{condition}{%
  \algobreak
}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}}]{Prof.\ van Duck}
Prof.\ van Duck is an esteemed scientist at the University of Quackland.
\end{IEEEbiography}
\end{document}
```

[image: condensed screenshot of the output]